# Partial template specialization with non-type parameters: GCC vs MSVS

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

Consider this simple template specialization:

```
template<typename T, size_t I>
struct S {};

template<typename T>
struct S<T, std::tuple_size<T>::value> {};
```

GCC does not compile it, as it uses template parameter `T` in the template argument `std::tuple_size<T>::value`:

> error: template argument 'std::tuple_size<_Tp>::value'
>   involves template parameter(s)

Now let's replace `T` with `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` in `tuple_size` template argument:

```
// Using primary structure template from previous example.
template<typename T>
struct S<T, std::tuple_size<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value> {};
```

This code still uses template parameter in template argument, but GCC compiles it without any errors or warnings. Why?

Now if we try to compile the second example using MSVS with `/std:c++latest` flag, it stops with error [C2755](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5fhx6s4.aspx):

> non-type parameter of a partial specialization must be a simple
>   identifier

What is this strange restriction? I want to stop compile-time recursion when `I` becomes equal to tuple size.

So who of them is wrong: MSVS or GCC?

Note that MSVS reports the error even without any template instantiations, while GCC works fine with all of these instances:

```
S<std::tuple<int, float>, 9> s1;
S<std::tuple<int, float>, 2> s2;
S<int, 42> s3;
```

I use MSVS Community 2015 Update 3 with it's default compiler and GCC 6.2.1.

Tried Clang 3.8.0. It does not compile both snippets with an error similar to GCC's message:

> error: non-type template argument depends on a template parameter of
>   the partial specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific section of the standard dealing with the viability of a partial class template specialization has been changed lots of times over the last few years. The original restrictionin [temp.class.spec.match] read:

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple *identifier*.

Your code clearly runs afoul of that, `std::tuple_size<T>::value` is not an identifier.

It then changed, after [cwg issue 1315](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1315), to read:

> Each *template-parameter* shall appear at least once in the *template-id* outside a non-deduced context.

But we're okay there - `T` is used in a non-deduced context as the first template parameter. And after [template `auto`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html), it now reads:

> If the template arguments of a partial specialization cannot be deduced because of the structure of its
>   *template-parameter-list* and the *template-id*, the program is ill-formed.

But we're okay there too. It can be deduced, you have the right "structure" - your specialization is using a non-type template parameter in the same location as the primary, and they should match fine.

---

I think following the resolution of 1315 (which I think is *post*-C++14), the code should be well-formed, but both gcc and clang reject it. An unfortunate fix would be to use two *type* parameters instead:

```
template <class T, class I>
struct S;

template<typename T>
struct S<T, typename std::tuple_size<T>::type> {};

template <size_t I>
using size_ = std::integral_constant<size_t, I>;

int main() {
    S<std::tuple<int>, size_<1>> s;
}
```

Both gcc and clang accept that one.

Comment: A very simple fix for clang is to add an explicit cast (`std::tuple_size` also supports `sizeof()`):
```template<typename T>
struct S<T, (size_t) std::tuple_size<T>::value> {}```

What I don't understand is why gcc doesn't accept `T` on it's own, but is fine with `T::something`:
```template<typename T>
struct S<T, std::tuple_size<typename T::something>::value> {};template<typename T>
struct S<T, std::tuple_size<T>::value> {};```