# C++ template specializations failing with non type parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, non-type

My question might be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142800/partial-template-specialization-with-non-type-parameters-gcc-vs-msvs), but I think I don't have a "partially specialized non-type argument expression" here, or don't understand the relation.

The following code produce an internal error with MSVC14 compiler (CPP11):

```
template<typename T, T... Elmts>
struct NonTyped
{

};

template<typename T>
struct is_NonTyped_of_type
{
    template<typename TL>
    static constexpr bool check = false;

    template<T... Elmts>
    static constexpr bool check<NonTyped<T, Elmts...>> = true;
};

cout << is_NonTyped_of_type<int>::check<NonTyped<int, 5>> << endl;
```

Using only one non-type parameter instead of a non-type parameter pack would work as expected, but this fails.

*Is this forbidden or undefined by the standard ?  What rule does it break ?*

*Any workaround ?*

Thank you very much!

**Edit**

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522065/c-template-specializations-failing-with-non-type-parameter-pack/44522522#44522522) given by [@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller) did actually not work with MSVC14, but is very helpful to understand the problem we have here. Thanks a lot for your help, StoryTeller!

Answer (score 2):

Clang accepts your code, while GCC did not. The partial specialization of your variable template should be okay as it is. You can always go back to the tried and tested way of using a regular class template to do the actual calculation.

```
template<typename T>
class is_NonTyped_of_type
{
    template<typename TL>
    struct check_impl : std::false_type {};

    template<T... Elmts>
    struct check_impl<NonTyped<T, Elmts...>> : std::true_type {};

public:
    template<typename TL>
    static constexpr bool check = check_impl<TL>::value;
};
```

Comment: I'm so puzzled by the fact that the compiler doesn't handle each of this possibility in the same way! Thank you, I had no idea that the fact I was using `constexpr` instead of `struct` was the reason for this strange behaviour here!

Comment: @Michel - Yeah, the handling of alias/variable tempaltes is weird sometimes. There's a few language defect reports to attest to that. The most robust way is to use classes like one would do in C++03. Then just have the alias/variable expose the result in a convenient fashion. The standard library does that even with newly added type traits.

Comment: This comment is **very** useful! Thank you very much!

Comment: @StoryTeller Wouldn't standard libraries do that anyway to support compiling with older standards(-std=c++98)?

Comment: @PasserBy - What do you mean? Some of the traits in newer revisions don't have the language support required in older standard revisions. It wouldn't make sense to compile them with older standards. They are usually behind a conditional compilation barrier.

Comment: @StoryTeller I didn't realize there were practically no traits before c++11 :P

Comment: @PasserBy - There were if you take boost into consideration. And one should always take boost into consideration ;) Those guys just implemented those things the really hard way, they are heroes.

Comment: The solution you give does not work with MSVC14 compiler! (Target Plarform Version 8.1 if that matters.) Then I did a mix of yours and mine and it works (structs with one Elmt set taken out from the pack)

Comment: @Michel - I attest to not checking it on MSVC14. But I'm not surprised MSVC has issues. Sorry it didn't work as is.

Comment: No worries. Always interesting to dig this things out! So the target platform does not matter here, and it seems it is not taking out one Elmt from the pack that solves the problem, but giving a specialized version for and empty NonTyped (no elemts). I've no idea of what I'm doing, but it's amazing ^^

Comment: I actually don't have a solution :( It compiles, IntelliSens shows the right result, but when compiled, it gives the wrong result... Sorry, I'll unmark as solved :/