# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with template specialization for a `sizeof...()` template value

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Another "who's right, between g++ and clang++?" question for standard gurus.

Given the following trivial code

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t...Is>
struct foo<sizeof...(Is), std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { };

int main ()
 {
    foo<3u> f;

    (void)f; // just to avoid the "unused variable" warning
 }
```

I have that clang++ compile without problems (clang++ 9.0.0, by example, but also older versions) where g++ (g++ 9.2.0, by example, but also older versions) give me the following compilation error

```
 prog.cc:8:8: error: template argument 'sizeof... (Is)' involves template parameter(s)
     8 | struct foo<sizeof...(Is), std::index_sequence<Is...>>
       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The question, as usual is: who's right?

Or, in other words: is correct my code example?

**-- EDIT --**

About the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142800), I suppose is related, but I don't think this one it's an exact duplicate.

In fact clang++ doesn't compile the code in that question, compile this code.

Otherwise the g++ error is the same and, if I understand correctly, the accepted answer of that question could be an answer also for this question.

Following that answer, if I understand correctly, the code is wrong **before** [cwg 1315](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1315), because "A partially specialized non-type argument expression" (`sizeof...(Is)`) involve "a template parameter of the partial specialization" that isn't "a simple identifier".

After cwg 1315 -- again, if I understand correctly -- the code should be correct because "Each template-parameter" appear once "outside a non-deduced context".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial template specialization with non-type parameters: GCC vs MSVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142800/partial-template-specialization-with-non-type-parameters-gcc-vs-msvs)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - interesting; I don't think it's an exact duplicate (clang++ doesn't compile the code of that question but compile the code of this one) but seems to me that the answer of that question could be an answer (or useful to write an answer) also for this one. Question edited. What do you think?

Comment: Looks like a bug in gcc like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67593