# How to specialize template using operator?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to sum the number from 1 to N-1 by TMP. so I wrote a source code as shown below, but an error `template argument '(number - 1)' involves template parameter(s)` occurred. Do you happen to know how to deal with this?

```
template <int number, int i = 1>
class Sum {
    public:
        static const int result = i + Sum<number, i + 1>::result;
};

template <int number>
class Sum<number, number - 1> {
    public:
        static const int result = number - 1;
};

int main () {
    const int result = Sum<10>::result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PicaudVincent I use gcc 7.4.0 (with -std=c++17).

Comment: See [CWG Issue 1315](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1315) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143510/580083).

Comment: @leftclick Oh sorry, In fact it only works with clang( std=c++17)  and fails with gcc. Sorry for the noise. You can see: https://godbolt.org/z/yJwYwv

Comment: Why not simply use a `constexpr` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC still follows [the rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#The_argument_list):

> Non-type argument expression cannot use the name of the template parameter except when it is exactly the name of the template parameter.

To solve the problem using template specialization, you can wrap the second non-type template parameter into an `std::integral_constant` to make it a type template parameter:

```
template<int number, class i = std::integral_constant<int, 1>>
struct Sum {
    static constexpr int value = i() + Sum<number, 
       std::integral_constant<int, i() + 1>>::value;
};

template<int number>
struct Sum<number, std::integral_constant<int, number - 1>> {
    static constexpr int value = number - 1;
};

static_assert(Sum<10>::value == 45);
```

Alternatively, you can use `if constexpr` and no partial specialization:

```
template<int number, int i = 1>
struct Sum {
    static constexpr int value = [] {
        if constexpr (number == i + 1)
            return i;
        else 
            return i + Sum<number, i + 1>::value;
    }();
};

static_assert(Sum<10>::value == 45);
```

Yet another way is given by fold expressions:

```
template<class> struct Sum_impl;

template<int... numbers>
struct Sum_impl<std::integer_sequence<int, numbers...>> {
    static constexpr int value = (... + numbers);
};

template<int number>
struct Sum : Sum_impl<std::make_integer_sequence<int, number>> {};
```